# Can you use Traffic Manager with blob storage or Azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions, azure-traffic-manager

I have a simple bit of JSON from an Azure Traffic Manager request, so ideally it would be stored in a blob storage account that is marked with a public access policy to read the blob. When I attempt this - using external endpoint in ATM - I get a 400 HTTP response.

The endpoint shows online in the portal, which is interesting since issuing that URL through the browser also results in a 400 error. I have the health probe pointed at a public blob at the $root container.

My second attempt was to then try an Azure function as the endpoint, and in this case the health probe results in a 'stopped' state. From older articles it appeared this would be returned for a basic App service plan (this is a consumption plan), but I presume that's outdated at this point?

What's the resolution here?  This shouldn't be this hard!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, I checked this issue on my side and I could encounter the same issue as you mentioned. Then I found issues about [Traffic Manager and Blob Storage](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SqlServer/en-US/665089ae-1f8b-485b-a2a3-490726ded788/traffic-manager-and-blob-storage?forum=WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork) and [Integration of Azure Functions with Traffic Manager](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/214).

Per my understanding, Traffic Manager does not support integration with Blob Storage, you could add your feature request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking).

For integrating with Azure Functions, you need to make sure your Web Apps at the **Standard** SKU or above are eligible for use with Traffic Manager. For web apps below **Standard** SKU, you could leverage [Azure Functions Proxies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies#a-namemodify-requestsamodifying-backend-requests). Here are some references, you could refer to them:

[Traffic Manager - Web Apps as endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-endpoint-types#web-apps-as-endpoints)

[Azure Functions Traffic Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42834857/azure-functions-traffic-manager)